# Hot to add a list of parameters of another object in jpa Criteria

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have a class Director

```
   public class Director {
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name="transacao_id")
      private Company company;
      private Date registrationDate;

       ...
   }
```

I have a class Company

```
   public class Company {
      private Long id;
      private String cnpj;
      private String description;

       ...
   }
```

I need to add another filter in predicates...

I need to fetch a list from **Director**, filtering through a **list of cnpj** using jpa predicates, for example:

```
private Predicate[] criarRestricoes(FilterDTO filter, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<Director> root) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        Date today = new Date();

        if (filter.getRegistrationDate() != null) {

            predicates.add(builder.between(root.get("registrationDate").as(Date.class), today, filter.dateParam));

        } 

       if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter.getCnpj())) {

            predicates.add(builder.equal(???????????, ???????????????);

        } 

        return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
builder.equal(root.join("company").get("cnpj"), filter.getCnpj());
```

Comment: @Peter Šály Thanks a lot, you're correct, but I did change, because I need to pass a cnpj list (SQL IN): 

`predicates.add(root.join("company").get("cnpj").in(filter.getCnpj()));`